# Cygwin C File returns "Bad Address" when using execv

Tags: java, c, exec

I wrote a little java program that I want to execute when windows starts.  I wrote a batch file to run when the OS starts, but I realized it won't work because windows 7 stops any batch file from running when the operating systems starts.

To get around this, I wanted to write a c program, compile it with cygwin (so that its .exe), and have this run when the operating system starts.  I want it to execv the command:

java -jar ipsetup.jar

I couldn't get it to work, so I tried to just have the c program execv the "ls" command.  Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

//argv[0] = "java";
//argv[1] = "-jar";
//argv[2] = "c:/windows/ipstartup.jar";

execv("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls");
printf("%s",strerror(errno));
return 1;
```

}

I keep getting the error "Bad Address" or "File or Directory does not exist." Anyone know why?

Thanks

**Edit

So I can get the program to run correctly within cygwin (it executes my java file).  But when I run it in windows, it outputs only the print statement.  Originally, it said cygwin1.dll was missing, so I put it in the Windows directory.  Here's my source code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

```
//argv[0] = "java";
//argv[1] = "-jar";
//argv[2] = "c:/windows/ipstartup.jar";


system("java -jar c:/windows/ipstartup.jar");
printf("I am here");
return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two potential sources of error here and they are similar to the batch file problem: cygwin and/or java might not work at Windows startup.

Why did you make this a cygwin program?  Is there something wrong with using the [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) function and regular ANSI C?

Comment: I didn't try system().  Let me try now.

Comment: system() worked perfectly.  Ty.  Do you have any idea why the regular exec wouldn't work?

Comment: For starters, you're calling the wrong variant of exec.  `execv` expects is 2nd argument to be an array of `char*` arguments to be passed to the program.  The way you are calling it, you should have used `execl`.

Comment: When using system("java -jar ipstartup.jar"), when I run the program in windows, it doesn't seem to execute this statement.  Any idea why?

Comment: is the java executable on your `PATH`? (i.e. what happens when you type java at the windows command prompt?)  How about on the path of the user account this startup script runs as?

Comment: if I execute java -jar ipsetup.jar in cmd, it runs fine.  Task scheduler is taking care of it running at startup.  Right now, I can't get windows to execute it by itself though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12201/discussion-between-thehouse-and-magn3s1um)